# Can't pass extra args to CSS Houdini paint function?

Tags: css, reactjs, css-houdini, css-paint-api

I have a React/Electron app (with .scss files and CSS modules) where I'm trying to use CSS Houdini `paint()` function. I've successfully managed to call it, but it appears adding a second argument to `paint()` is causing it to fail.

styles.module.scss:

```
.container {
  --bubble-color: #ccc;
  background-image: paint(testPaint, selected);
  display: flex;
  margin: 4px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  height: 75px;
}
```

testPaint.js:

```
registerPaint(
  "testPaint",
  class {
    static get inputProperties() {
      return ["--bubble-color"];
    }
    static get inputArguments() {
      return ["*"];
    }
    paint(ctx, geom, properties, args) {
      console.log('args', args); // NOTHING LOGGED HERE
      const isSelected = args[0].toString() === "selected";
    }
  }
);
```

If I exclude `selected` from the `paint(testPaint, selected)` call, it works fine, but with `args` being an empty array. If I call it with `selected`, instead it doesn't get called at all (no console log, no breakpoint trigger). I'd been following [this guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Painting_API/Guide#Passing_parameters) and didn't see it mentioning any other requirements to get this to work...

Answer (score 1):

Seems like passing arguments to `paint` is not supported by all browsers (tested on FF and Chrome on mac).

**With arguments**

[image: screenshot from chrome debtools style panel]

**Without arguments**

[image]

> Note: It would be great to parameterize the colors, too, wouldn’t it? The spec allows for the paint() function to take a list of arguments. This feature is not implemented in Chrome yet, as it heavily relies on Houdini’s Properties and Values API, which still needs some work before it can ship.

[source](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/01/paintapi#parameterizing_your_worklet:%7E:text=It%20would%20be%20great%20to%20parameterize%20the%20colors%2C%20too)

Comment: I saw this too, which I find weird... I did `process.versions["chrome"]` in my Electron dev tools, and it returns `85.0.4183.121`. According to https://ishoudinireadyyet.com, that means Props and Values should be in this version of Chrome?

Comment: `Props and Values` is a different api which, indeed, under "houdini umbrella" but not related the the "paint" api. [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Properties_and_Values_API#:~:text=The%20CSS%20Properties%20and%20Values,do%20not%20inherit%20their%20value)